# Is it possible to have a CNAME record on a domain point to a nameserver and have the nameserver serve records?

Tags: dns, bind, nameservers

I have two nameservers, namely ns3. ns4. and I would like have the nameservers names changed for multiple domains, but the process takes time, so for the time being I would like to do the following:

```
ns1.<domain> CNAME ns3.<domain>
ns2.<domain> CNAME ns4.<domain>
```

And

```
ns3.<domain> A IP
ns4.<domain> A IP
```

If I then set the nameservers for a domain to `ns1` and `ns2` would the nameserver records on `ns3` `ns4` get resolved?

Comment: "I would like have the nameservers names changed for multiple domains" This needs to happen at the registrar of each domain, it is not only a DNS change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make that a `NS` record be a `CNAME` record never.

What you can do is to have the `NS` record pointed to a `A/AAAA` or a `CNAME` record.

So if you need to mass change an NS route you must adjust the `CNAME` or the `A/AAAA` that is pointing to.

Since `NS and A and AAAA and CNAME` are different types of records (with different functions), you must update each one, unfortunately.

But referring to change:

```
IN NS ns1.example.com.
IN NS ns2.example.com.
```

to

```
IN NS ns3.example.com.
IN NS ns4.example.com.
```

This must be changed in the NS record one by one.

### If I then set the nameservers for a domain to ns1 and ns2 would the nameserver records on ns3 ns4 get resolved?

Yes, if you make something like.

```
EXAMPLE.COM. IN NS NS3.EXAMPLE.COM
EXAMPLE.COM. IN NS NS4.EXAMPLE.COM
EXAMPLE.COM. IN CNAME NS3 NS2.EXAMPLE.COM
EXAMPLE.COM. IN CNAME NS4 NS1.EXAMPLE.COM
EXAMPLE.COM. IN A/AAAA NS2 [SOME IP GOES HERE]
EXAMPLE.COM. IN A/AAAA NS1 [SOME IP GOES HERE]
```

This for sure will resolve.

Comment: "What you can do is to have the NS record pointed to a A/AAAA or a CNAME record." No, see RFC 1912: "Don't use CNAMEs in combination with RRs which point to other names
   like MX, CNAME, PTR and NS. "

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, please if you don't mind, edit the given answer